# What does a ~ mean after a file name in UNIX (bash)?

Tags: unix, vim

When I create a file using vim and save it, for eg. main.c, two copies are created:
main.c and main.c~. They have the same contents. Why is this happening and what does the ~ mean?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234221/218196.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is just a convention to indicate a backup file.

Comment: What should I do about it? I don't want a separate backup file to be present when I commit stuff using git.

Comment: Create a .gitignore file and add `*~` to it.

Comment: You can also turn this off in `vim` - see the `backup` and `writebackup` options

Answer (score 1):

it is used to indicate the backup file. even in Microsoft office products when you open any file, same file is created with same name beginning with `~`  but it is hidden.